# How does coreboot installation work?

Tags: bios

I wonder how coreboot can be installed on a modern mainboard at all. Modern mainboards only accept signed images. And because coreboot does not have the private keys they can't sign their images. So it should get rejected when trying to install.

For example all modern Android phones only accept signed images. But mods can be installed because the manufcaturer offers an option to "unlock the bootloader". I am not aware of a similar feature on modern PC mainboards.

Coreboot could use exploits but I think it's hard to find exploits for all mainboards.

So how does the coreboot installation process work?

Comment: Why was this voted to close? I want to know how coreboot installation process works. Why is it opinion based?

Comment: The premise (installing Coreboot and using it for exploits) is opinion in nature from my point of view.

Comment: @John I think you did not understand. Exploits are needed to install firmware on devices that normally block modificated firmware. As you see I meant something completely different.

Comment: This sounds like a very theoretical question. You haven't stated that you're trying to install core boot and having problems doing so, you're just opining on a narrow set of technology and asking our opinion on it too.

Comment: I disagree that this is opinion-based. It may be off-topic, but it is a clear question with a clear answer: You program the storage chip directly.

Comment: I don't understand why this should be opinion-based. I got a great answer and either it's wrong or right. I can't see any opinion in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coreboot is generally not designed to be installed later. Like BIOS or UEFI firmware, it’s supposed to be installed in the factory, as the hardware is made.

On systems without flash protection/signatures, it can be installed using software. Otherwise, you need to program the firmware flash ROM directly, usually by removing it from the board and using programmer hardware. If the chip is not socketed, partial or full desoldering may be required.

---

Unlocked Android phones are not at all comparable because aftermarket „ROMs“ are the OS, not the firmware. PCs have a similar locking mechanism, Secure Boot.

Comment: Maybe you can also answer these two questions: Are exploits also used to install coreboot when it's normally blocked? Are there (open) mainboards which allow modification of the firmware?

Comment: No. Yes. Though these open mainboards often already come with Coreboot. You can find out more about that in the [end-user info page](https://www.coreboot.org/users.html) of Coreboot.